# Where do I put the code to add the watermark?

Tags: pdftex, pdf, python, watermark

Total newbie here. I downloaded TeXLive so that I could generate PDF from my Sphinx project. Now I'm trying to put a watermark on the PDF. I read this on this forum:

```
\usepackage{draftwatermark}
\SetWatermarkText{DRAFT}
\SetWatermarkScale{1}
```

But where do I put this code? I am used to editing the `conf.py` file. Is there a different place?
Thanks.

Comment: ...and I wish you...welcome in this excellent community named TeX.SE.

Comment: You only have to write  `\usepackage[options]{draftwatermark}` in the preamble, says the documentation.

Comment: In conf.py:  `latex_elements['preamble'] = r'...'`

Comment: Thanks, but couldn't get it to work. Used Acrobat instead. I put the latex_elements line after the Options for HTML output. Tried it before. Still couldn't get out of the gate with syntax error.